# Querying related tables in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

So I have two tables Employee and Details like this.

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('employee_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    ............

class Detail(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'details'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('detail_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(50))
    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'))
    employee = relationship("Employee", backref=backref('details', order_by=id))
    ............
```

Now what I want to do is get all the employees and their corresponding details, here is what I tried.

```
for e, d in session.query(Employee, Detail).filter(Employee.id = Detail.employee_id).all():
    print e.name, d.email
```

The problem with this is that it prints everything twice. I tried using .join() and also prints the results twice.

What I want to achieve is like

```
print Employee.name
print Employee.details.email
```

Comment: Maybe there are two query results so that it will be printed twice. What's the query result?

Comment: Well it prints the results like this
    John Doe, john@gmail.com
    John Doe, john@gmail.com
    Groot Root, groot@gmail.com
    Groot Root, groot@gmail.com

Comment: Please add the `SQL` query that is produced by running this query, as it really should not produce any duplicates. Or if your real code has some other joins or where clauses, please show them too for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really care only about few columns, you can specify them in the query directly:

```
q = session.query(Employee.name, Detail.email).filter(Employee.id == Detail.employee_id).all()
for e, d in q:
    print e, d
```

If you do really want to load object instances, then I would do it differently:

```
# query all employees
q = (session.query(Employee)
        # load Details in the same query
        .outerjoin(Employee.details)
        # let SA know that the relationship "Employee.details" is already loaded in this query so that when we access it, SA will not do another query in the database
        .options(contains_eager(Employee.details))
        ).all()

# navigate the results simply as defined in the relationship configuration
for e in q:
    print(e)
    for d in e.details:
        print(" ->", d)
```

As to your `duplicate` result problem, I believe you have some "extra" in your real code which produces this error...

Comment: Thank you, your second suggestion should work. I didn't know about .outerjoin() and .options()