# SQLAlchemy getting dates outside between()

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Why is this query getting dates outside the range of between(). I'm trying to get planes and their bookings for 1 specified day.

For example:

```
print start
2015-04-17T00:00
print end
2015-04-17T23:59
```

The query:

```
planes = Plane.query.filter(Booking.start_date.between(start, end))


for p in planes:
    plane = p.as_dict()
    bookings = []
    for b in p.bookings:
        booking = b.as_dict()
        print booking['start_date']
```

Results in:

```
2015-04-17 02:30:00
2015-04-16 03:00:00
2015-04-16 02:30:00
2015-04-17 05:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

If you enable logging of the SQL statements produced, you will see that your query is missing a `join` clause. In order to fix it, you need to make sure that you are filtering *only* on bookings of each plane separately, which is as simple as adding a `join(...)` to the query:

```
q = (session.query(Plane)
     .join(Booking)
     .filter(Booking.start_date.between(start, end))
     )
```

This will return *planes which have **at least** one booking for the specific date range*. However, iterating over planes, when you access their bookings via relationship (`p.bookings`), `sqlalchemy` will load **all** bookings for each plane.

If you really only want *only* the filtered bookings, you either have to do the filtering again (which is OKEY for small data sizes), or you can use `contains_eager` to achieve this.
See [Querying related tables in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395087/querying-related-tables-in-sqlalchemy) on how this can be done, but basically you will end up with:

```
q = (session.query(Plane)
     .join(Booking)
     .filter(Booking.start_date.between(start, end))
     .options(contains_eager(Plane.bookings))
     )
```

Comment: I tried using contains_eager() but got this error: "'Plane.bookings' does not support object population - eager loading cannot be applied."

Comment: Just curious, what would the code look like with the extra filter?

Comment: just another `.filter(Booking.my_column == my_value)`

Comment: Any ideas on why this error occurs when I use contains_eager: "'Plane.bookings' does not support object population"?

Comment: Also when I add another .filter(...) it still includes bookings outside the between

Comment: Does it work as expected without this *another* filter?